# import sub module in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am making a Shared library with the following structure

- src

  - modules

    -- module1.ts

    -- module2.ts

    -- index.ts `// reexports from module1.ts and module2.ts`
  - utils.ts `// exports someUtils`
  - logger.ts
  - index.ts `// re-exports from utils.js and logger.js`

Now in my service-A and service-B I can do something like

`import { someUtil } from '@project/shared` since `someUtil` is exported in the main index.ts, but how can I access something exported from `module1.ts` without having to do `import { module1Variable } from '@project/shared/src/modules/index` ?

Comment: Export it in your index.ts

Comment: Well the problem with that is that it will be loaded when I import anything from the main index.. I dont want for example service-B to run things from module-2 just because i import `someUtil`